# Should the href attribute still be set with Angular?

Tags: angular, angular7

I wonder whether there is a good reason to set (or not to set) the `href` attribute on internal links in an Angular 7 single-page application.

It works with or without, as Angular uses the `routerLink` attribute.

Comment: `routerLink` is loading your component/modules etc via `router-outlet` without refreshing the page (you want this for an SPA), `href` is reloading your page/application or navigating to a different site etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Angular Router uses `routerLink` directive, the `href` attribute is still the only solution for external links, e.g. `https://stackoverflow.com`.

Using both `routerLink` and `href` does not make any sense as long as the latter one gets overwritten by the `routerLink`.

Answer (score 1):

`href` will reload the page, where as `RouterLink` is a directive that just leaves the SPA state as is and brings the `Component` attached to the `route` in the `router-outlet`

I believe there are other subtle advantages like setting the `routerLinkActive`